# PostgreSQL different datatypes in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a database which contains 2 tables - tests and questions(for those tests).
[image]

Questions table has a column called **right_answer** which might be an **array of strings** or a **single string**. 
[image]

So, I'm wondering what is the best approach to store data in this case? Should I have several questions tables for an each answer type or there's some other way?

Maybe I can store my `right_answer` using only one table somehow?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, but it doesn`t answer my question

Comment: Nevertheless: you should [not post code as images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okay, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly normalized model should always be your first approach:

```
create table questions
(
  id       integer generated always as identity primary key,
  type     text not null,
  test_id  bigint references tests
);

create table answers
(
  id               integer generated always as identity primary key,
  question_id      integer not null references questions,
  answer           text not null,
  is_right_answer  boolean not null
);
```